# Allowed access to content script globals from a chrome.tabs.executeScript injected code?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, code-injection

I read in the documentation that javascript executing on a page can't access variables and functions of content scripts (see [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment)). But if I use the following simple code in the background.html:

```
<script src="/path/to/caller.js"></script>
```

where caller.js contains just

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { code: 'alert(test)'});
}
```

and a well-manifested content script defines

```
var test = 42;
```

alert() correctly appears and shows the 42 value. So I can access the 'test' global.
So did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Content scripts execute in a special environment called an isolated world. They have access to the DOM of the page they are injected into, but not to any JavaScript variables or functions created by the page.*

`chrome.tabs.executeScript` and manifest injected `content_script` are both executed in the same environment. The documentation is specifying that your extension code does not have access to variables or functions from the website itself.

Comment: Ok, I see. My error was to consider the injected code as if it were incorporated somehow like a <script> tag and therefore executed as page script.